# If Object Doesn't Exist, Returns Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, object, typeerror

If `customer_id` doesn't exist in the Shopify JavaScript object, I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'customer_id'):

```
function () {
  if ("customer_id" in Shopify !== "undefined") {
    return Shopify.checkout.customer_id;
  } else {
    return ShopifyAnalytics.meta.page.customerId;
  }
};
```

- When it does exist, the function works. When it doesn't, it produces the Uncaught TypeError.
- If the conditional statement is `if ("customer_id" in Shopify) {` then when the property exists, it fails the condition.
- If the conditional statement is `if ("customer_id" in Shopify.checkout) {` then when the property exists, it meets the condition. But when the property doesn't exist, it produces the Uncaught TypeError.

The `hasOwnProperty()` method is not used because I need to check for inherited properties in the object. What's the right way to check if an inherited property exists in an object?

Comment: Please share more details, like the programming language you use and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Clarified the language. Attempts are shared with the various conditional statements.

Comment: `"customer_id" in Shopify !== "undefined"` can never be false. `"customer_id" in Shopify` will be `true` or `false`, and `(true or false) !== "undefined"` will always be true. You seem to be mentally mixing up `in` with the `typeof` operator somehow.

Comment: How is it possible then that when `Shopify.checkout.customer_id` is defined, the condition of `"customer_id" in Shopify` is not met?

Comment: Because `customer_id` exists on `Shopify.checkout`, not on `Shopify`?!

Comment: You probably want `if (Shopify.checkout && Shopify.checkout.customer_id)`.

Comment: @deceze If the Shopify.checkout check is used, when the property doesn't exist, a TypeError is produced. Your solution of `if (Shopify.checkout && Shopify.checkout.customer_id)` works for both conditions. Why does both conditions need to be used?

Comment: Apparently `.checkout` may not exist, and if it exists, it may not have a `.customer_id` property. So you need to check both to avoid both pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

```
"customer_id" in Shopify
```

This will always resolve to a boolean, never to undefined, afaik so you need to remove the !== 'undefined' part on the check.

Also the way you have structured that, in case the property is not found on the first, you force the other, while it may well be null or undefined there as well, and this is the error you are having.

```
ShopifyAnalytics.meta.page.customerId // meta.page could be undefined
```

Somewhere during runtime you evaluate "undefined.anything" and so you get the " can not read property anything from undefined"

Comment: If the first object doesn't exist, then `ShopifyAnalytics.meta.page.customerId` will exist.

Comment: The main issue is to remove the !==, as the check always resolve to boolean, never to undefiined. But you could also write some check code for the rest of the path used, just for security, allthough i get what you mean